# Generating and Saving HABTM Data in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, has-and-belongs-to-many, cakephp-2.7

**Edit: Cake version 2.7**

In my app I have a Wedding model which has a HABTM relationship with Users.
When I'm logged into as the admin user I want to be able to add a new Wedding and by doing so generate and save 2 additional users to login with different roles.

```
public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
    'User' => array(
        'className' => 'User',
        'joinTable' => 'weddings_users',
        'foreignKey' => 'wedding_id',
        'associationForeignKey' => 'user_id',
        'unique' => 'keepExisting',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => '',
        'limit' => '',
        'offset' => '',
        'finderQuery' => '',
    )
);
```

Is my Wedding model and is replicated back on the User model.

When I run the basic create action I get this:

```
Array (
  [Wedding] => Array
    (
        [name] => james and sally
        [ceremony_date] => Array
            (
                [month] => 06
                [day] => 26
                [year] => 2015
                [hour] => 02
                [min] => 29
                [meridian] => pm
            )

        [venue_id] => 1
    )

[User] => Array
    (
        [User] => 
    )
)
```

I can then Create Additional users using the $this->Wedding->User->create() method and putting them into the array. The Wedding saves, the users save (With problems more further on) however the association doesn't save. Even using the

```
$this->Wedding->saveAssociated($saveData)
```

method.

**Additional Problem**
The beforeSave function doesn't seem to be called and my users are entered into the DB with blank passwords.

```
public function beforeSave($options = array()) {
    if (isset($this->data[$this->alias]['password'])) {
        $passwordHasher = new BlowfishPasswordHasher();
        $this->data[$this->alias]['password'] = $passwordHasher->hash(
            $this->data[$this->alias]['password']
        );
    }
    return true;
}
```

I assume it's something to do with my $this->data array but I havn't got that far yet.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please state the version of CakePHP you are using. It is hard for people to help you without knowing that!

Comment: @drmonkeyninja sorry, Friday afternoon tiredness is setting in. Edited original post.

Comment: @RossSteele Try and save a wedding object with associated users and do `$this->Wedding->saveAll($data, array('deep' => true))` to save the associations. See if this helps: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#saving-related-model-data-habtm